# Modx vs Yii as an application framework

Tags: yii, modx

I am developing a mobile web application (with jQuery mobile) with a lot of application logic required (mainly database access) and with the necessity of creating it as flexible as possible (I am following OO PHP with ORM).

Through a lot of research on PHP frameworks I reached to the conclusion that Yii is the most promising framework now. Recently, i crashed into modx revolution. Even though I am not looking for a CMS system, its approach as a CMF system and its clear separation of templates, snippets and chunks offers great extensibility.

What is your opinion on advantages of each model (especially on learning curve)?

Comment: This may be hard to get opinions since both yii and modx are smaller communities on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

I would say if you're trying to create a web application use a framework like Yii(though Symfony looks pretty promising too IMHO)

If you're building a website, then MODx is fine (in fact awesome)

By website I mean the typical page-content relation (like most company websites)

By application I mean a less single-page content site, like a property search site or stackoverflow

MODx is my, hands down, favorite CMS for creating websites above 5 pages. But not so long ago I was faced with a similar question, framework or modx? I ended up going for a risky choice.. that is MODx Revolution. And regretted it... revo was quite new then and among all issues I've found it being slow the worst. I'm sure newer versions are faster, but you know what they say about first impressions. Anyway, Evo is still king in my books, but that aside...

Ok, well here's where it breaks down. The big reason why would not chose a CMS (even as good as modx:) is the database structure. In all CMSes the database is geared toward displaying pages, so you'll have the typical title,linkage,content,meta etc. While modx makes adding additional fields a breeze through template variables, creating many-to-many and one-to-many relationships is somewhere between impossible and really hard. (think delimiting strings, creating a separate table, creating widgets for custom templates to deal with multiple items). If you go with a framework you have to implement a lot of goodies most CMSes have already figured out, like fckeditor implementation, image uploader, user management, and so on.

Another advantage of a framework that creative routing is a lot simpler to implement. CMSes have a harder time with that, though not impossible.

But if you're comfortable with a framework (or wanting to use this to learn it) you might be better served going the framework route. That is if you trust yourself to implement better security than MODx.

good luck

Comment: So you sound more like you are saying use modx for the stuff they have already written but watch out for a few pitfalls that made you regret using it... is that right?

Comment: Yes. This reply is a few years old, modX may have changed quite a bit since, but I would summarize it in a different way now as `Do what you're comfortable with` that is, if you have good knowledge of PHP and SQL, you can write your own CMS equivalent that suits your needs exactly, otherwise rely on the work others have put into a product that makes creating a website easier and faster.

Comment: Thanks & makes sense.
We are planning on using modx or concrete5 for the authentication schemes, admin interface, and tested code base as the basis for a web app. I've looked into using a framework (the only two I've really used to any degree are CodeIgniter & Zend) & writing or adapting tested & reliable code for those 2 purposes & time wise it just doesn't seem to make sense.
(NOTE: this app won't ever have 1000s of users were talking 10 to 20 for now & if we think it makes sense, maybe up to the low hundreds @ most[not likely though])

Answer (score 3):

We used MODx to create eco2data.com which is a web application containing a mix of dynamics pages-content on environmental projects and application-page (portfolio management for example)

We reviewed frameworks and CMF and decided to go with MODx evo. It handle well and easily all the login stuff (creation of users, login, access rights) and help us to separate php code from template. We use MODx elements as follow :

- Model: php files calling the business DB
- View: Template/Chunk
- Controller : snippet code that include php files containing the Models (object), process info and call

Most of the business content is stored in another DB, and our MODx pages only contains ph

Drawbacks are most of the code is stored in MODx DB, so it is hard to work with version control system.

Comment: So, we have picked modx revo for our current web app project & have found that most, if not all, of the code can be created as external files (which I modify in my IDE & store in source control).
Additionally I found information from Bob (http://bobsguides.com/custom-db-tables.html) on how to utilize custom DB tables (a requirement for me). So even the DB creation scripts can be put in source control...